Need Support to remove domain from blowfish blocklist, new dev here
Is there another way? I don't have any Solana developer friends, even though I sent all my info to them.
Hello,
Thank you for the information. In order for us to proceed further with your request, we suggest having someone known and established in the Solana developer community reach out to us via twitter @blowfishxyz, or email on your behalf to vouch for you.
Thank you in advance,
Blowfish

Hey did you ever get this resolved ?
